# How would you re-write the production rules for an existing grammar so that semi-colons were optional?

Tags: parsing, syntax, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

Suppose that there was a programming language **Mod(C)** just like **C++** except that it *was* white-space sensitive.

That is, parsers and compilers written for **Mod(C)** did not ignore line-feeds, spaces, etc...

Also suppose that someone had already written down the production rules for describing a formal grammar for this modified version of **C++**

My question is, how would you modify the production rules so that semi-colons were optional in the event that the semi-colon was followed by a line-break?

Actually, the semi-colon would optional if some `<optional_semi_colon>` token is followed by:

- one or more spaces and tabs
- zero or one line-comments
- a line-break (`\n\r` or `\r\n` or `\n` or `\r`)

The following piece of code would compile just fine:

```Cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        cout << i << " "; // there is a semi-colon here. that's okay
    }
    return 0 // no semi-colon on this line
}
```

Comment: To make sure I understand what you’re proposing - is the only change that newlines would count as semicolons? Or are you proposing a Python-style system where indentation matters?

Comment: Consider the code `int x = a + b;`. If I insert a line break between `a` and `+`, with your system we’d get the resulting statements `int x = a;` (a variable declaration and initialization) and `+b;` (an application of the + operator to `b` whose result is ignored). That could break backwards compatibility. Would you be okay with this?

Comment: Sounds like what awk does.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear what you mean by "white-space sensitive" and your example doesn't show any white-space sensitivity other than the possible optionality of semicolons at the end of a line. That is, you don't seem to be looking for an implementation of the [off-side rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule), as with Python or Haskell, where indentation indicates block structure. [Note 1]

Presumably, you are not just asking how to turn any newline into a semicolon, since that would be trivial. So I assume that you want something like JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI), which automatically inserts a semicolon at the end of a line if:

1. the line doesn't already end with a newline, and
2. the current parse cannot be extended with the first token of the next line, either because

   - 2.1. there is no item in the current state's itemset which would allow the next token to be shifted, or

   - 2.2. the items which might allow a shift have been marked as not allowing a newline.
     [Note 2]

Provision 2.1 prevents the incorrect semicolon insertion in:

```js
let x = a
+ b
```

On the other hand, there are cases when you really want the newline to end the statement, in order to avoid silent bugs, such as:

```js
yield
/* The above yield always produces undefined. */
console.log("We've been resumed");
```

`yield` -- and other statements with optional operands -- are annotated in the grammar with `[No LineTerminator here]`, which triggers provision 2.2 and thus allows ASI even though the next token (`console` in the above example) could otherwise have extended the parse. Another context where newlines are banned is between a value and the postfix `++` operator, so that

```js
let v = 2 * a
++v
```

is accepted with the (presumably) intended meaning. (Without ASI, there would be a syntax error *after* the `++`, where ASI is not allowed because there's no newline character.)

JavaScript is not the only language with optional command terminators, but it's probably the language with the most elaborate set of rules controlling the parse. Other languages include:

- Python, which in addition to the off-side rule, ignores semicolons inside parentheses, braces and brackets;
- Awk, which treats newlines as statement terminators unless the newline follows one of the tokens `,`, `{`, `?`, `:`, `||`, `&&`, `do`, or `else`.  [Note 3]
- Bash, in which a newline is a command terminator except in specific contexts, such as after a `|`, `||` or `&&` operator or a keyword like `do`, `then` and `else`, and inside an array literal or an arithmetic expansion. [Note 4]
- Kotlin, whose rules I don't know. And undoubtedly other languages as well.

JavaScript (and, I believe, Kotlin) suffer from an ambiguity with function calls, because

```js
let a = b
((x)=>console.log(x))(42)
```

is parsed as calling `b` with the argument `(x)=>console.log(x)` and then calling the result with the argument 42. (Which is a runtime error, because the result of `console.log` is `undefined`, which cannot be called.)

There are also languages like Lua, in which semicolons are always optional, even if you run statements together on a single line (`a = 3 b = 4`), and which therefore also suffers from the misinterpretation of function call expressions. However, unlike JavaScript, Lua requires that the `(` be on the same line as the function expression, and therefore flags the equivalent of the above example as a syntax error. (The check is not part of the grammar, for what it's worth: After the function call is parsed, a semantic check is performed to verify that the line number of the `(` token is the same as the line number of the last token in the function expression.)

I went to the trouble of enumerating all of the above examples by way of illustrating the fact that optional semicolons are not a simple grammatical transformation, and that there is no simple rule which can determine the precise circumstances in which a newline is an implicit statement terminator. Realistic implementations of the feature are non-trivial, and differ in their details; the algorithm chosen needs to be tested against a variety of realistic code samples, and it needs to be carefully documented so that programmers using the language don't find themselves surprised by the results. If you get it wrong, but your language nonetheless becomes popular, you'll find projects with style guides which require semicolons even in context in which they were optional. None of that is intended to imply that you shouldn't pursue the idea; only that it is perhaps more complicated than it looks at first glance.

Having said all that, I don't believe that any of the above examples require a context-sensitive grammar (unless you want to implement the off-side rule). Even in the case of JavaScript, possibly with some minor exceptions, a parser can be created by starting with an LALR automaton and then adjusting the transition rules, state by state, in order to either ignore a newline token or reduce it to a statement terminator (as well as implementing the lookahead restrictions in certain rules). Most of these modifications will effectively be simply the deletion of one conflicting parser actions, similar to the operator-precedence-based resolution of ambiguous expression grammars. (And it's worth noting that most parser generators make no attempt to rewrite the original grammar after processing of the precedence declarations.)

However, while the existence of a PDA demonstrates the existence of a context-free grammar (at least for a context-free superset of the target language [Note 5]), it does not demonstrate the existence of a simple or elegant grammar. It seems to me likely that recreating a grammar from the modified PDA will produce a bloated monster without much value as a discursive tool. The modified PDA itself is sufficient to perform the parse, so reconstructing a grammar is not of much practical value.

---

#### Notes

1. That's perhaps just as well, because the off-side rule is not context-free, and thus cannot be implemented with a context free grammar. Although there are well-known techniques for implementing in a lexical scanner.
2. That's a slight oversimplification of the ASI rules. In some cases, JavaScript also allows a semicolon to be inserted before a `}`, even if there is no newline at that point. But that's not a significant complication.
3. `?` and `:` are a Gnu AWK extension.
4. That's not a complete list, by any means. See the Posix shell grammar and the bash manual for more details.
5. While the published grammars for the languages mentioned above, like the grammars for C and C++, are nominally context-free grammars, they do not actually encompass the entirety of the well-formedness rules in the respective language standards and/or manuals, which include constraints (or "early errors", in the terms of ECMA-262), "that can be detected and reported prior to the evaluation of any construct". Many of these rules are clearly context-sensitive (such as prohibitions on multiple definitions of the same name in a lexical scope).

   Context-sensitive parsing is not necessarily a bad thing. Sometimes it's a lot simpler than trying to achieve the same result with a context-free grammar (as in the case of Lua function calls mentioned above). But it's certainly convenient to parse as much as possible using a generated parser, since such a parser can more easily be repurposed for other applications, such as linters, code browsers, syntax highlighters, and so on, not all of which need to be as precise as a compiler.